# Javascript location.reload() loses parameters (empty $_GET)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

If I am at page

test.php?parameter1=some&parameter2=some

and I execute the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function($) 
         {

                    //window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                    //window.location.href += "#mypara";
                    //location.href.reload();
                    location.reload();
        });
</script>
```

the location.reload() function loses any $_GET parameters (Notice I tried without any result using the window.location.replace() function).

It seems the location reload has the correct location.href with correct parameters but the request is sent to the server without $_GET set, by debugging with PhpStorm indeed I see no $_GET is set.

Searching on the internet I found no working solution to pass $_GET parameters when issuing location.reload().

Comment: right now i run location.reload on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431408/javascript-location-reload-loses-parameters-empty-get?as=as and params dont gone

Comment: Try location.reload(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
location.reload(true); //It load document from server
```

If you write `location.reload()` then it will  reloads the page from the cache.